# Prove or disprove, that there is a partial order in N that is also an equivalence relation.

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, relations

I gave my answer based on the impossibility of a relation to be both symmetric and antisymmetric at the same time. I was wondering how to give a proper formulated answer to this.

Comment: Suppose we have the relation $R = \{(a, a), (b, b), (c, c), (d, d)\}$ defined on the set $S=\{a, b, c, d\}$ .  (This means $aRa, bRb, cRc, dRd$).  Check through the properties of the relation, whether: reflexive, symmetric, antisymmetric, transitive. (1) Reflexive: for every element $x \in S$, $(x, x) \in R$.  Symmetric:  For every $a, b \in S$ **THEN $(b, a) \in R$.  Satisfied, since for all pairs $(x, y) \in R \rightarrow (y, x)\in R$ (vacuously).

Comment: **Antisymmetric** (which is not the same property of asymmetry):  Is it true that **IF** for all pairs in $R$,  $((x,y) \in R \land (y, x) \in R) \to (x = y)$?  Indeed.  Transitivity also follows :vacuously.  So the relation $R = \{(a, a), (b, b), (c, c), (d, d)\},$ defined on $S = \{a, b, c, d\}$ is **both** an equivalence relation **and** a partial order.

Comment: OOPs correction on the second to last comment: Symmetry: For every $a, b\in S$, whenever $(a, b) \in R$ we must have $(b, a) in R$.  Since every element in S is related only to itself, we have, $\forall x \in S$, $(x, x) \in R \to (x, x \in R$.(hence the term "vacuously true."

Answer (score 2):

$$
x\preceq y \,\,\text{ if and only if }\,\,x=y.
$$
Then $\preceq$ is a partial order *and* an equivalence relation on $\mathbf{N}$.

Answer (score 1):

Let's assume we have a partial order $?$ that is also an equivalence relation. Let's see what we can deduce about $?$.

Suppose there are $a$ and $b$ such that $a ? b$. Then since $?$ is symmetric, we have $b ? a$. Combining these, since $?$ is antisymmetric, we have $a = b$. Thus if we ever have that $a ? b$, we must have that $a = b$. But since $?$ is reflexive, if $a = b$ then $a ? b$. Thus $?$ is the same relation as $=$, and we can check that $=$ is both a partial order and an equivalence relation.

Comment: @amWhy, I showed that any partial order that is also an equivalence relation must be identical to the ordinary equality relation. And since the ordinary equality relation is both a partial order and an equivalence relation, we see no contradiction. It seems circular, but it isn't.

Comment: Sure, once it is assumed that we have any partial order/equivalence relation, it is going to act like "=".  There was no need to assume that; all that was needed to prove "There exists" blah blah that foos and fies, is to introduce a specific blah blah that foos and fies.  In this case, that would be the equality relation. "There exists "R" such that $aRb \iff a=b.$

Comment: But I think I see what you were trying to do:  Let's suppose we have such a relation that is ordered and an equivalence relation.....then......and ....which requires.....such that .... Indeed we see that the equality relation is such a relation.... So, not a problem. I'll delete my first comment.

Comment: @amWhy, my solution not only shows the existence of such a relation, but also its uniqueness.